# What is the proper way to get the iconURL for an NMACategory in the Here Places API?

Tags: react-native, here-api

I have an array of `NMAPlaceLink` objects that I am using for a search function. To add an icon for search results, I first get the category for the `placeLink`, and then get the `iconURL` for that category. However, the icon string is still empty after reading the `iconURL` property. Am I doing something wrong?

```
(void)request:(NMARequest *)request didCompleteWithData:(id)data error:(NSError *)error{
  if ( ( [request isKindOfClass:[NMADiscoveryRequest class]]) && (error.code == NMARequestErrorNone)) {
    NMADiscoveryPage* page = (NMADiscoveryPage*) data;
    NSArray<NMALink*> *results = page.discoveryResults;
    NSUInteger size = [results count];
    for (int x = 0; x < size && x < 8; x++) {
      NMAPlaceLink *place = ((NMAPlaceLink *)results[x]);
      NMACategory *cat = place.category;
      NSString *icon = cat.iconUrl;
      if (icon)
      {
        NSLog(@"icon -> %@", icon);
        [icons addObject:[NSString stringWithString:icon]];
      }
      else{
        NSLog(@"no icon");
        [icons addObject:[NSString stringWithString:none]];
      }
    }
  _result = (NMADiscoveryPage*) data;
}
```

The console logs `no icon` instead of the `iconURL`.

Comment: NMAPlaceLink does have category, Instead of NMACategory, NMAPlace should fetch the iconURL for the place, Please try to replace with NMAPlace

Answer (score 0):

NMAPlaceLink does have category, Instead of NMACategory, NMAPlace should fetch the iconURL for the place, Please try to replace with NMAPlace